# Couldn't match expected type ‘[foo]’ with actual type ‘Maybe [foo]’

Tags: haskell, monads

I have two record types:

```hs
data Attribute = Attr {
    attName  :: Text,
    attValue :: Text
} deriving (Show, Generic)

data Attributes = Attrs {
    attributes :: [Attribute]
} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

In `main` the `contents` value holds a `Maybe [Attribute]` which I'm trying to shovel into the `Attrs` constructor:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    bytes <- readFile "data/file.json"
    contents <- pure (decode bytes :: Maybe [Attribute])
    let attributes = Attrs { attributes = contents }
    print attributes
```

Running this generates the following error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Attribute]’
              with actual type ‘Maybe [Attribute]’
• In the ‘attributes’ field of a record
  In the expression: Attrs {attributes = contents}
```

How to apply the `Attrs { attributes = something }` constructor when `something` is a `Maybe [Attribute]` instead of directly an `[Attribute]`?

Comment: What do you want the list to contain if the `Maybe [Attribute]` is `None`?

Comment: `x <- pure y` is equivalent to `let x = y`, so `x` will have the same type as `y`, i.e. `Maybe [Attribute]` in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the `Nothing` case, where decoding fails. Here's a possible way to do it.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    bytes <- readFile "data/file.json"
    case decode bytes :: Maybe [Attribute] of
       Nothing -> putStrLn "Error: can't decode the file!"
       Just contents -> do
          let attributes = Attrs { attributes = contents }
          print attributes
```

It's likely that the `:: Maybe [Attribute]` part is redundant, since the compiler can infer that type from the rest of your program. Still, you might want to leave it there to make the code more readable to humans.

Note that the `decode` library function was designed to return `Maybe [Attribute]` instead of `[Attribute]` so that it can both report errors (decoding failed) and *force* the caller to handle such errors. In this way the programmer can no longer "forget" to check for errors since the types won't match.

If `decode` didn't do this, `decode` would need to either crash the program (horribly inconvenient) or report a dummy value (e.g. `[]`), which could be mistaken for an actual input, and allow the caller to forget to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to live dangerously:

```
let Just contents = (decode bytes :: Maybe [Attribute])
```